# Make jQuery UI Slider values work as links

Tags: javascript, jquery, user-interface, hyperlink, slider

How can I make the jQuery slider values work as links. Like if someone scrolles to for example 1920, it redirects them to another page.

I have inserted the code in a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/up6Bx/

Hope you can help me.

Thanks in advance.

HTML:

```
<div id="slider-range-max"></div>
```

jquery:

```
$(function() {
    var araObj = new Array( 1900, 1920, 1960, 1975, 1976 );

    $("#slider-range-max").slider({
            min: 0,
            max: araObj.length,
            value: 0,
            create: function() {

                for (i=0;i<=araObj.length;i++)
                {
                    $(this).append($('<span></span>').css("left",((i+0.85)*(100/araObj.length))+"%").addClass("slider-digit").text(araObj[i]));
                };
            }
        });

    console.log(araObj);
});
```

Comment: Please correct your fiddle. include external libraries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$(function() {
    var araObj = new Array( 1900, 1920, 1960, 1975, 1976 );

    $("#slider-range-max").slider({
            min: 0,
            max: araObj.length,
            value: 0,
            create: function() {

                for (i=0;i<=araObj.length;i++)
                {
                    $(this).append($('<span></span>').css("left",((i+0.85)*(100/araObj.length))+"%").addClass("slider-digit").text(araObj[i]));
                };
            },
        change: function(event, ui) { 
             var val=ui.value;
         if(val == 1)
         {
         window.location.href='http://www.amazon.com';    //same tab
         }
         else if(val == 2)
         {
         window.open('http://www.yahoo.com');//new tab
         }   
          } 
        });

    console.log(araObj);
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/up6Bx/6/)

Comment: It looks great, but not exactly what I meant. Now you get a popup. But I want each value to have a different link. Is that possible?

Comment: Yes, that was what I meant, but it doesn't seem to work in the fiddle, does it? http://jsfiddle.net/up6Bx/4/

Comment: Thank you so much!! Exactly what I wanted. I'm sorry for bothering you, but is there also a way to make the link open in the same window, so that it won't open a new tab?